# How to tag place or location in Facebook SDK for Android

Tags: android

I need to add location to a picture post done through facebook sdk in android,

I tried useing the setPlaceId() method available in sdk as below,

```
SharePhotoContent sharePhotoContent =
                new SharePhotoContent.Builder().setPhotos(photos).setPlaceId("My Location").build();
```

But it throws 500 error, can anyone please suggest some options, I dont what to use Graph API to share the location